# Different Consumers reading data from different keys in a partition from a Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

[image]

If I have a Kafka topic in which I have only one partition[P0] and a producer writes data into the partition[P1] with different keys[k1,k2].. let's say [1-1,1-2] are the values of the key k1 and 2-1,2-2,2-3 are the values of the key k2.

I now have [1-1,1-2,2-1,2-2,2-3] in the partition[P0] of a Topic

Can I have two different consumers[C1, C2] listening to the partition[P0] in the topic and read values that are associated with different keys...as in C1 reads the values of ONLY k1 and C2 reads ONLY the values of K2?

Answer (score 0):

A single partition of a topic can only be consumed by one consumer instance within the same consumer group. Therefore your consumers C1 and C2 need to have different consumerGroups if they both want to read from the same partition.

Following that rule you can then have C1 filtering out the messages with key K1 and C2 filtering the messages with key K2.

Another option would be (only if you have control over the producer) to write a custom partitioner that writes all messages with key K1 into Partition0 and all messages with key K2 into Partition1. That way you can have two consumer instances/threads with the same consumerGroup reading the two partitions in parallel.

Comment: Yes the second option is more feasible...but can I have kafka.console.consumer.sh do the filtering or should I altogether use Streams API for this filtering process..?

Comment: I do not think I can answer this question. Just planning to filter data is not really a use case so I cannot give advice on this without know how much data you are processing, how often, in which environment the application will run etc... Please provide much more details so people can help you. Also, as you are being new to Stackoverflow it is common to ask one question, get an answer (or multiple answers) and then accept the answer if it helped you. In case you have new questions please create a new question while providing all required details for someone to answer.